# Is it possible to make ActionBar tabs height higher than ActionBar height? If so, how?

Tags: android, android-layout, actionbarsherlock, android-actionbar

I'm using ActionBarSherlock

In a similar question about ActionBar tabs height, I used:

```
<style name="YourTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo">
   <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/blah1</item>
   <item name="android:actionBarTabStyle">@style/blah2</item>
   <item name="android:actionBarSize">80dp</item>
   ..
</style>
```

And I assumed I could use this specific attribute on each style instead

```
<item name="android:actionBarSize">80dp</item>
```

And individually adjust ActionBar height from ActionBar tabs height.

But it doesn't work.

So, is this an Android design principle I cannot override?

That the tabs must always be the same height as the ActionBar.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% on this but from my experience it can't be done, android do not allow it. Maybe this will change in the future but for the moment there's not much that can be done about it.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try with a custom action bar? You can completely customize the actionbar with a seperate layout.

This [sample](https://github.com/prijupaul/Priju/tree/master/CustomActionBar) will show you how.

Answer (score 0):

You can override the android design principle for action bar, I have tried and it may work for you.

Copy the following code in styles.xml file

```
<style name="ThemeSelector" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/myTheme.ActionBar</item>
</style>

<style name="myTheme.ActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">imageforactionbar</item>
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/myTheme.ActionBar.Text</item>
    <item name="android:height">60dp</item>
</style>
```

1) Place the image in the drawable folder

2) write the style theme 'myTheme.ActionBar.Text' in the style xml.

```
<style name="myTheme.ActionBar.Text" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/app_head</item>
</style>
```

Change the manifest file accordingly, include

```
android:theme="@style/ThemeSelector"
```

under application tag.

Answer (score 0):

you can override the the action bar

getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.action_bar);

```
android:layout_width="@dimen/action_BarWidth"
android:layout_height="@dimen/action_BarHeight"
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't change the size of native action bar on ICS. The height of native action bar is always 48dip(portrait) or 40dip(landscape).

But you can implement your own action bar if you insist on changing its height.

Answer (score 0):

we can create the action bar dynamically from code in java class or from theme :

Step 1:We can change the image,name ,colour,height ...etc of the action bar for the particular class this is one process .

```
    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
   // show the action bar title
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
    LayoutParams test = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, Gravity.CENTER | Gravity.CENTER);
    View actionBarView = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(
            R.layout.x, null); // layout which contains your
                                            // button.
    actionBar.setCustomView(actionBarView, test);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);

    SpannableString s = new SpannableString("Test");
    s.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.parseColor("#ffffff")), 0,
            s.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

    // Update the action bar title with the TypefaceSpan instance
    actionBar.setTitle(s);
```